# Use Cases of Neo4J and Spark GraphX

Tags: scalability, graphs, neo4j

I have used Neo4J to implement a content recommendation engine. I like Cypher, and find graph databases to be intuitive.

Looking at scaling to a larger data set, I am not confident No4J + Cypher will be performant. Spark has the GraphX project, which I have not used in the past.

Has anybody switched from Neo4J to Spark GraphX? Do the use cases overlap, aside from scalability? Or, does GraphX address a completely different problem set than Neo4J?

Comment: Hi, I do have the same query regarding scaling issue of Neo4j. And now I decided to go for Titan DB. Titan is an open source distributed graph database build on top of Cassandra.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neo4j and Spark GraphX are meant for solving problem at different level and they are complimentary to each other.

They can be connected by Neo4j's Mazerunner extension:

> Mazerunner is a Neo4j unmanaged extension and distributed graph
>   processing platform that extends Neo4j to do big data graph processing
>   jobs while persisting the results back to Neo4j.
>
> Mazerunner uses a message broker to distribute graph processing jobs
>   to Apache Spark's GraphX module. When an agent job is dispatched, a
>   subgraph is exported from Neo4j and written to Apache Hadoop HDFS.
>
> After Neo4j exports a subgraph to HDFS, a separate Mazerunner service
>   for Spark is notified to begin processing that data. The Mazerunner
>   service will then start a distributed graph processing algorithm using
>   Scala and Spark's GraphX module. The GraphX algorithm is serialized
>   and dispatched to Apache Spark for processing.
>
> Once the Apache Spark job completes, the results are written back to
>   HDFS as a Key-Value list of property updates to be applied back to
>   Neo4j.
>
> Neo4j is then notified that a property update list is available from
>   Apache Spark on HDFS. Neo4j batch imports the results and applies the
>   updates back to the original graph.

Check out this tutorial to get an idea on how to combine the two:
http://www.kennybastani.com/2014/11/using-apache-spark-and-neo4j-for-big.html

Comment: Providing a summary of external links' content would be useful.

Comment: I will accept the answer after you provide a summary from the external link. Thanks.

Comment: I just updated the answer to add a summary